# How Sinon stubs function of an class that used internally

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I wanna understand if Sinon can be used to stub a function from another class that is called internally.

For example there is a dbutil class:

```
class DBUtils {
    getMyResult(var1, var2){
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            console.log("calling real getMyResult");//I still see this in the log
            resolve(var1 + var2);
        });
    }
}
module.exports = DBUtils;
```

It is called in another class dummyService:

```
const dbUtils = new DBUtils();
class dummyService {
    getResult(var1, var2){
    //initially in my code, it returns a promise, 
    //but I have replaced it with your code
    return dbUtils.getMyResult(var1, var2).then(item =>{
        console.log("finish getting my result!");
        console.log("here is my result: " + item);
        return item; 
    });
}
module.exports = dummyService;
```

Here is my unit test file: (Applied code change suggested by @Mark_M)

```
describe("dummy Test", function () {
var service = new DummyService();

const stub = sinon.stub(DBUtils.prototype, 'getMyResult');
stub.resolves("1234");    

it("get result", function() {
    service.getResult("ab", "cd").then(item => {
        console.log(item);
    });
});
});
```

Can anyone help me understand why my Stub is not working? and How could I stub the getMyResult function inside dbUtil class?

================ SOLUTION ===================

There are 2 things I missed:

1. I should stub the DBUtils.prototype

> ```
> sinon.stub(DBUtils.prototype, 'getMyResult').resolves("1234");
> ```

2. there is a typo when I import the DBUtils in my test.

inside dummyService, I have

```
const DBUtils = require(./dbutils);
```

however, in the test file, I have

```
const DBUtils = require(./DBUtils);
```

Somehow, sinon didn't complained about it, and that's why my stub get never injected in the original method....after I correct the import in my test, I can see the stub result get injected now.

Comment: @Mark_M, I finally figured out why it's not stubbing as expected...in my test.js, my DBUtils is set to required (./DBUtil) where it should be (./dbutil). So it's actually a typo.... I wonder if there is way can detect this kind of mistake....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `getMyResult()` is a class method on your `DBUtils` class, you need to stub the prototype of `DBUtils`. Something like this:

`DBUtils.getMyResult()` returns a promise. So you don't need to re-wrap it in a promise in `dummyService.getResult()`. It makes it a lot easier to reason about (and test) if you just return the original promise:

dummyService:

```
const DBUtils = require('./DBUtils')

class dummyService {
    getResult(var1, var2){
        const dbUtils = new DBUtils() // <- I assume you are making an instance somewhere
        return dbUtils.getMyResult(var1, var2).then(item =>{
            console.log("finish getting my result!");
            console.log("here is my result: " + item);
            return item // <- if you want to access item in then you need to return it
        });
    }
}
module.exports = dummyService;
```

Now in test.js:

```
const DBUtils = require('./DBUtils')
const DummyService = require('./dummy')
const sinon = require('sinon')

// stub the prototype
const stub = sinon.stub(DBUtils.prototype, 'getMyResult')
stub.resolves("Stubbed: 1234")

// make an instance of the service
const service = new DummyService()
service.getResult("ab", "cd").then(item => {
    console.log(item)
    // this prints 'stubbed: 1234'
    // item is "abcd", which is the returned value of the real getMyResult method.
    // the expectation is, item should be "1234" as specified in the stub.
});
```

Comment: Hmm…are you importing `DBUtils` into your test module? Also, in your example you are trying to stub and instance returned from `new DBUtils()` that won't work. You need to stub the actual class (i.e. what returned from require('DBUtils') and then all instances of the that class made with `new DBUtils()` should then have the stubbed method. The code above works with the class you have in your question, so there must be a disconnect somewhere.

Comment: Sorry It was my bad, the error is not coming from the stub. I have resolved it. However, the stub is still not working as expected. Let me edit my post with the code change, so it's easier for you to read. Thanks again for the follow up!

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspoke - getMyResult returns a promise already. So in your service, you don't need to wrap it in another promise. Let me see if I can work up and example and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I wanna unit test getResult() in dummyService. As you can see, getResult() will call dbUtils.getMyResult() internally.  So the actual goal of this test is to test the logic of .then() of dbUtils.getMyResult() (which I wanna stub in this case)

Comment: @Thanks Mark_M, I have updated my code following your example, but the stub is still now working. I will update my code in my main post so you can take a look at it.

Comment: So that's frustrating. When I copy and paste your code  I get stubbed results. I have three files: DBUtils.js, dummy.js, and test.js. I run it with `mocha ./test.js` and get the stubbed result without the `console.log()` in `getMyResult()` (one change I made: your'e missing `}` in dummyService.)

Comment: Thanks @Mark_M, my issue resolved. It's a typo in the require statement causing this frustration....I wanna punch myself after I found this silly mistake :)